# Can you charge your phone "airside" at Malaga Airport (AGP)

Tags: airports, electronic-items, power, airport-terminals, malaga

I normally travel from (Kastrup) Københavns Lufthavn (CPH) where there are many outlets where you can just "plug-in" and charge your equipment without any cost.

Are there any public outlets, inside and after the security checks at Malaga Airport (AGP), where you could charge your phone, laptop, etc for free?

Answer (score 5):

For these questions, Sleeping In Airports is usually a great resource.

https://www.sleepinginairports.net/guides/malaga-airport-guide.htm

> Mobile Charging –  Chargers are available in the work zones.

> Work Zones – There dedicated work areas which offers desks and outlets for charging devices. Locations: T3, Airside, Floor 2, Boarding area x 2 locations.

Do note however, that even SiA is affected by Covid:

> Airport tips and suggestions in this guide and elsewhere on the site were written before March 2020 and may no longer be valid. [...] We will start updating all of our guides in October 2021.